# JqueryUI tabs: how to maintain selected tab during post-back?

Tags: c#

I am using jQuery tabs. There are 8 tabs. In each tab there is a form. I am facing this problem: when user enter the data of a form (for example in 5th tab) after saving its come back to first tab. I want to come back on same tab after post back I tried this:

**my asp code is this**

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="aid" value="0" />
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <div class="container">
           /a> </li>
                <li><a href="#test">Content 5</a> </li>
               tent">
```

Answer (score 3):

Save the value of selected tab in cookie (or some other place) and then restore that value on page refresh.For saving the value of cookie you can check the following jquery plugin

[jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    active   : $.cookie('activetab'),
    activate : function( event, ui ){
        $.cookie( 'activetab', ui.newTab.index(),{
            expires : 10
        });
    }
});
```